# Отладка Release-конфигурации в Linux

Tags: linux, отладка

Можно ли как-то на Linux по release-конфигурации и core файлу узнать место, где в программе произошла ошибка (конкретно, номер ассемблерной инструкции, которая привела к ошибке).

При использовании gdb не понятно в каком конкретно месте упала программа:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00005633bd506050 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Как-то так: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/how-to-handle-stripped-binaries-with-gdb-no-source-no-symbols-and-gdb-only-sho . Плюс поглядеть strace-ом.